# Make Website run on localhost

Tags: macos, localhost

I recently started developing a Website. However, I am having trouble running it on localhost. When I type `http://localhost` in my web browser, it seems to be working. I still however cannot get my .php files to run on the server. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: i presume you've installed phpMyAdmin?

Comment: read this http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-phpmyadmin-working-osx-10-10-yosemite/

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure the web server you've chosen to use to treat the `.php` files as executable scripts.

How this configuration looks depends on the web server you're using. For example, in Apache, your configuration might have something that looks like this:

```
    <Directory /absolute_path/to/your/scripts/directory>
        AddHandler cgi-script cgi pl
        Options ExecCGI FollowSymLinks Indexes
        # ....
    </Directory>
```

Note that this one is for Perl scripts, but should give you a good idea of what you need to look for.

Don't forget to restart the server after updating the configuration files.